# sql query where difference of latest date in current year and current date is in range on join

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. vehicle and service dates.

```
vehicle
id | vin | type | no_of_wheels | chassis_number |
------------------------------------------------
 1 | QWE | Car  |      4       | AIZI2Q
 2 | ASD | Bike |      2       | AIQQWA
 3 | ZXC | Car  |      4       | AIQQIWA
 4 | JKL | Bike |      2       | AZZZZZZ

service_dates 
id | vin | last_service_date
-----------------------------
1  | QWE | '2020-11-15'
2  | ASD | '2020-10-10'
3  | QWE | '2021-01-10'
4  | ASD | '2020-11-15'
5  | ASD | '2021-01-10'
6  | ZXC | '2020-12-12'
7  | QWE | '2021-01-20'
8  | ASD | '2021-01-20'
9  | JKL | '2021-03-01'
```

I want to generate a query where I want to list all the vehicles whose service is pending. The logic is that the most recent last_service_date is more than 30 days prior to today("2021-03-04") and only the last_service_date in the current year need to be considered, if there is no last_service_date in current year for that vehicle, then that vehicle automatically qualifies for service.

so the output should be:-

```
vehicle
id | vin | type | no_of_wheels | chassis_number |
------------------------------------------------
 1 | QWE | Car  |      4       | AIZI2Q
 2 | ASD | Bike |      2       | AIQQWA
 3 | ZXC | Car  |      4       | AIQQIWA
```

Explanation:- since the most recent last_service_date for QWE and ASD is more than 30 days before today they are listed. and since ZXC is not done this year, it also qualifies. But JKL was done just 4 days ago so that is not listed.

what I have so far:-

```
Select v.* , max(sd.last_service_date) 
from vehicle v Left JOIN service_dates sd on sd.vin = v.vin
and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(sd.sd.last_service_date AS DATE)) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())
and ((extract(day from now() - CAST(sd.last_service_date AS DATE)) - 30) > 0))
group by v.vehicle_guid;
```

this won't work as it doesn't account for vehicles with no service date in current year, and the max(sd.last_service_date) is for selecting but it does not select the most recent service date.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please TAG only the database you are actually using

Comment: i am using postgres, i have edited the tags, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1f701fcdd5e33655926e29b8552d0140)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM vehicle v
LEFT JOIN (                                       -- 2
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (vin)                      -- 1
        *
    FROM service_dates
    ORDER BY vin, last_service_date DESC
) s ON v.vin = s.vin 
WHERE s.last_service_date IS NULL                 -- 3
    OR CURRENT_DATE - s.last_service_date > 30    -- 4
```

1. `DISTINCT ON` delivers only the first record of an ordered group. Your group is the vehicle's `vin` and you need to order these by the `last_service_date DESC` to get the most recent record to the top a the group. This ensure that you get only the most recent date per unique vehicle.
2. `LEFT JOIN` this result on the `vehicle` table. You need a `LEFT` join because, you said, there may be vehicles which don't have a service record yet. In that case this kind of join will create a `NULL` record for these vehicles.
3. Then you can filter your expected records. Of course you want get the `NULL` values because you expected all vehicles without a service record.
4. And you want to get all vehicles whose service record is more than 30 days away.

Comment: can you please explain why you gave s.last_service_date IS NULL?.
and also in the output, I only want the columns of the vehicle table.

Comment: This is for the case, that there's no entry in the service table for a certain vehicle. I'll add a full explanation in a few minutes :)

Comment: and is it possible to have only the columns of the vehicle table in the output?

Comment: of course... just take `vin` instead of the asterisk in the final select

Comment: thanks a lot, can you also help me with the query if I want to exclude the vehicles with no service date in the current year. I would be highly in your debt.

Comment: Sry for delay. Appended the explanation

Comment: Your last question: So you don't want to get all vehicles whose last_service_date was this year? But than you don't need the requirement with the 30 days anymore, correct?

Comment: no, 30 days still holds, just that all vehicles who have been serviced before 30 days just in the current year are listed. I think a where clause on the inner select should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's it